# Problem locating rows with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm new at SQL in general, so I'm have a few problems with some of my stored procedures I'm designing. My procedure takes in 3 parameters. A location (or table name basically, a varchar), a room number (varchar), and a phone number (char) in the form of 'xxx-xxxx'. Here is the code for the procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddPhoneNumberToRoom]
    @Location    varchar(25),
    @Room        varchar(10),
    @PhoneNumber char(8)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @String varchar(100);
    SELECT @String = ' UPDATE ' + @Location + 
                     ' SET PhoneNumber = ' + @PhoneNumber +
                     ' WHERE Room = ' + @Room;
    EXEC(@String);
END
```

The error I receive is:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Apartments_PhoneNumbers".  The conflict occurred in database "CMPhone", table "dbo.PhoneNumbers", column 'PhoneNumber'."

The phone number is in the PhoneNumber table, so when I do:

```
UPDATE Apartments SET PhoneNumber='123-4567' WHERE Room='2'
```

It works just fine. The `PhoneNumbers` table also looks like this, just has the one number in it.

```
PhoneNumber
-----------
123-4567
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PRINT @String;` will yield that it says `PhoneNumber = 123-4567` (which treats it like an expression, `123` subtract `4567`, which equals `-4444`), not `PhoneNumber = '123-4567'` like in the example you hard-coded. So you should be escaping the values you're appending with two single-quotes:

```
SELECT @String = ' UPDATE ' + @Location + 
                 ' SET PhoneNumber = ''' + @PhoneNumber + ''' 
                   WHERE Room = ''' + @Room + ''';';
```

But better yet, to better protect yourself from SQL injection (see [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server---part-1/), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server---part-2/), and [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)), you should have (a) check that `@Location` is a valid table, (b) `QUOTENAME()` it anyway, and (c) pass in the other two values as properly typed parameters rather than appending them to the string:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.' + @Location) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @sql = N'UPDATE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@Location)
           + N' SET PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber
                WHERE Room = @Room;';
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, 
      N'@PhoneNumber CHAR(8), @Room VARCHAR(10)',
      @PhoneNumber, @Room;
END
```

And even better still, you shouldn't have a separate table for each `Location` IMHO - Location should be a column. Then you wouldn't need dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: Ok, so I put the first section in (the escaping the values one) and I get an incorrect syntax near ' WHERE Room = ' ' error. Sorry, like I said, i'm new to SQL. The second one does work, but I need to work through the syntax so I know what's going on.

Comment: @user3268054 Try it now, just missed a string delimiter (again, this is another reason you should be learning the second form - less string escaping).